# Why is React behaving unexpectedly as JSX render both defined string and the JSX Element in React?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a simple code:

```
return x && <div>Hello World</div> // x = "test Member"
```

Please note that here x can or cannot be defined.

When the `x is defined as "Test Member"` I see output as:
[image]

`Hello World`

However I definitely remember getting output as: (In my web app):

```
Test Member
Hello World
```

[image]
Can someone tell me why I am seeing this unexpected behaviour? I am not able to reproduce the previous use case where both x string value and div content was rendered.

How does this work internally? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

In React, the behavior you are seeing is expected. When you use the logical AND (&&) operator in JSX, it works as a conditional rendering mechanism.

To achieve the behavior you described, where both x string value and the  content are rendered, you can modify your code like this:

```
 return (
  <>
    {x && <div>{x}</div>}
    <div>Hello World</div>
  </>
 );
```

Comment: no, I don't want that behaviour however I remember having that behaviour happening on its own I wanted an explaination on in which conditions that happens?

Comment: That should not hapeen at all ,may be you are missing something in your code changes .